# How put Leaflet Filelayer data into editable layer so I can edit after Upload

Tags: geojson, leaflet-draw

I am using “togeojson” and “Leaflet.FileLayer” for File upload in my leaflet draw using below Code:

```
    L.Control.FileLayerLoad.LABEL = '<img class="icon" src="folder.svg" alt="file icon"/>';
    var style = {color:'red', opacity: 1.0, fillOpacity: 1.0, weight: 2, clickable: false};
  var LoadFile =  L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
     position: 'topright',
    layer: L.geoJson,
    // See http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-options
    layerOptions: {style: {color:'red'}},
    // Add to map after loading (default: true) ?
    addToMap: true,
    // File size limit in kb (default: 1024) ?
    fileSizeLimit: 1024,
    // Restrict accepted file formats (default: .geojson, .kml, and .gpx) ?
    formats: [
        '.geojson',
        '.kml',
        '.gpx'
    ]
}).addTo(map);
```

How do I access upload file data so I can put it into editable layer and edit uploaded draw and save as geojson?

I have previously load geojson to leaflet draw and edite json + save to database but not success to get upload from directory.

Comment: I did this but not Work: 
 var LoadFileoption =  { position: 'topright', fileSizeLimit: 1024,}
   var geofile = L.Control.fileLayerLoad({
        layerOptions: LoadFileoption,
         onEachFeature: function (feature, layer)
        {
        var layers = layer;
        addPopup(layer);
        editableLayers.addLayer(layers);
}
}).addTo(map);
addNonGroupLayers(geofile, editableLayers);

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Leaflet.FileLayer does not upload data.  It reads it from a local file, client side, and renders it locally.  Uploading to a remote database is a separate operation.

Using your code, when you add a local layer, it will emit a 'data:loaded' event (see [documentation](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.FileLayer)).  On this event, initialize a [draw control](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) (or tweak an existing one) setting the 'edit' attribute of the draw control options to e.layer from the 'data:loaded' event.  That will make that layer editable.  The major gotcha here is the limitation on leaflet.draw: `Leaflet.draw does not work with multigeometry features such as MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon, or GeometryCollection`, so you may need to preprocess you data.

After editing, saving to a remote DB will depend a lot on your backend.  What server are you using?  If you have a server supporting WFS-T, it should be straightforward,  If you are using a Node server (especially with sockets), it is also relatively easy (just export your edited layer with toGeoJson and send to the server, where you can use something like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) to store in the database for instance.